# Verifying 802.3 auto negotiation

Tags: ethernet, power-over-ethernet, autonegotiation, data

This is my setup:

[image: PWR but not data.]

**The Problem**

The end point, ethernet device B, is powered by the power injector but receives no data. Everything is connected using CAT5 cable.

Ethernet device A signifies a GB/s ethernet connection by a lit LED on the front panel of the device. I assume that reflects the connection between device A and the network, and not from device A and the power injector. The left side of device A is connected to the network.

If I add a Netgear ProSafe GS105SE, Netgear GS116v2, Netgear ProSafe GS309P, Netgear Prosafe FS108, and a few other brands to include TP-Link, Asus, ZyXEL, and LevelOne in between Ethernet Device A and the power injector then power and data are able to communicate with endpoint ethernet device B.

**What my research has given me**

The 1000BASE-T data rate (GB ethernet), by convention is communicated over all  four pairs of a CAT5 cable. Auto-negotiation is a mandatory feature of 1000BASE-T (gigabit ethernet) and takes place over 2 of the four wires.

If two gigabit devices are connected through a cable, via any ‘Power Injector’ mentioned above, with only two pairs physically being used, of the required 4 pairs required for 1000Base-T data rate, the link will negotiate to gigabit as the default data rate however the data link will never establish since two required data lines are not present.

**My Conclusion**

From the data sheet of the I.T.E. PW182RD and PowerDsine 3501 power injectors, only two pairs are available to transmit data from the device A to the power injector while the remaining two pairs are not connected (NC) which are required for successful GB communication. Because of this, both the ethernet device A and endpoint ethernet device B default to a gigabit data-rate which requires 4 pairs for full-duplex communication which the power injector doesn’t support, therefore no data link.

[image: PW182RD J1 = LAN + Power to Device B J2 = LAN in from Device A]

**MY QUESTIONS**

1. How can I sniff/capture the auto negotiation packets (normal link
   pulses, and fast link pulses) to observe what is actually happening
   when the devices power up and perform auto-negotiation? Is there a
   tool that I can place in between device A and the power injector?
   Wireshark has been unsuccessful thus far.
2. Is there any reason why device A and device B, can't negotiate to
   10/100 data rate?
3. Why is it, when I add the Netgear switches in between device A and
   the power injector, does communication open up through the power
   injector and ethernet device B?

Comment: I tend to doubt your conclusions.  Both devices say they are 802.3af compliant, so they don't use separate pairs for power.

Comment: @RonTrunk - I updated my question with a picture of the PW182RD pinout.

Comment: The PW182RD is a 10/100 PoE injector, so you will never run 1G through it.

Comment: A1: with specialized hardware, yes. A2: your devices are broken; they should not link at Gig without verifying all four pairs. A3: because they *aren't* broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With gigabit endpoints (1000BASE-T) your injector needs to be gigabit capable as well.

Cheap injectors insert power on the pairs unused by 10BASE-T and 100BASE-TX while disrupting the data transmission on these pairs. This only works when one of the endpoints falls back to 100BASE-TX - while this is quite common it's not to be taken for granted.

The problem is that 1000BASE-T uses the same pairs as 10/100BASE-T/X for autonegotation "fast pulses" - both sides negotiate 1000 Mbit/s, but when they begin to pair up the lanes (in the <del>PCS</del> PMA sublayer) it fails. If one of the ports abandons 1000 Mbit/s negotiation in this situation you fall back to 100 Mbit/s. If both sides keep negotiating for gigabit it won't work.

If your switch has an "auto-100" setting you can use that to reduce autonegotiation to 10/100 Mbit/s.

A proper gigabit-capable injector uses magnetics between the in and out ports and couples the power onto the center taps, just like a PoE switch does.

> How can I sniff/capture the auto negotiation packets (normal link pulses, and fast link pulses)...

I don't think any NIC supports this. You'd need to use an oscilloscope.

> Is there any reason why device A and device B, can't negotiate to 10/100 data rate?

They might not be willing to try unless configured down to 10 or 100 - beware: when forcing a single speed you deactivate autonegotation in total. You need to manually set full duplex on both sides or, when this isn't possble, live wth half duplex.

> Why is it, when I add the Netgear switches in between device A and the power injector, does communication open up through the power injector and ethernet device B?

The Netgear switches appear to abandon GbE negotiation on <del>PCS</del> PMA pairing failure and fall back to Fast Ethernet as explained above.

Comment: Actually, every NIC has knobs to control the auto-neg process. Not all OSes provide the ability to tweak them. (linux: ethtool *advertise N* parameter.)

Comment: @RickyBeam Good point - that way, you could configure an "auto-100" set on the NIC yourself.

Comment: @Zac67 - Thank you for your thorough answer. CQ1.When you say "if your switch has an auto-100 setting" are you implying a managed switch? CQ2. When you mention PCS do you mean Physical Coding sublayer?

Comment: @Niko_Jako Yes, switch settings apply to managed switches only. Sorry, it's actually 1000BASE-T's Physical Medium Attachment sublayer that organizes the four lanes into a single link (check IEEE 802.3 Clauses 40.1.4 and 40.4).